# How to change an item that isn't the one I clicked in a RecycleView?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

**Summary**

I have a CardView in a RecycleView with a button to play or stop a song and only one song should be played at a time. So when I click one of this buttons, all the others should have a "play" icon while the clicked one should have a "stop" icon. Basically, I need to change the image of an item that I didn't click.

**The problem**

The project compiles, the songs don't overlap when multiples are played simultaneously and when I click an icon it changes to the other icon, but if I click another item, the previous one clicked don't change back and stays the same.

**Attempt**

So, I've tried to iterate over all the elements of the RecycleView, to change them back to a default icon and later just change the clicked icon, but I couldn't really access the other items that I didn't click. I've tried to reference the previous item with a global variable, but, again, I couldn't really handle this previous item.

**The AudioGridActivity code:**

```
public class AudioGridActivity1 extends AppCompatActivity {
private RecyclerView recyclerView2;
private MyAdapter2 adapter2;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

private ArrayList<CardAudioGrid> mList;

private MediaPlayer song;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_audio_grid1);
    createList();
    buildRecyclerView();

    final ImageView mediaPlayer = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mediaPlayerId); // this is the play/stop "button"

    adapter2.setOnItemClickListener(new MyAdapter2.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlayClick(int position) {
            switch(position){
                case 0:
                    pauseTheme();
                    song = MediaPlayer.create(AudioGridActivity1.this, R.raw.gato);
                    playTheme();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    pauseTheme();
                    song = MediaPlayer.create(AudioGridActivity1.this, R.raw.gato);
                    playTheme();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    pauseTheme();
                    song = MediaPlayer.create(AudioGridActivity1.this, R.raw.gato);
                    playTheme();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    pauseTheme();
                    song = MediaPlayer.create(AudioGridActivity1.this, R.raw.gato);
                    playTheme();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    pauseTheme();
                    song = MediaPlayer.create(AudioGridActivity1.this, R.raw.gato);
                    playTheme();
                    break;
                case 5:
                    pauseTheme();
                    song = MediaPlayer.create(AudioGridActivity1.this, R.raw.gato);
                    playTheme();
                    break;


            }

        }
    });

}

public void createList(){
    mList = new ArrayList<>();
    mList.add(new CardAudioGrid(R.drawable.mediaplay2, R.color.colorAccent, ""));
    ...
    mList.add(new CardAudioGrid(R.drawable.mediaplay2, R.color.colorPrimary, ""));
}

public void buildRecyclerView() {
    recyclerView2 = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewId2);
    recyclerView2.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
    recyclerView2.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    adapter2 = new MyAdapter2(this, mList);
    recyclerView2.setAdapter(adapter2);
}
public void playTheme(){
    if(song!=null) song.start();
}
public void pauseTheme(){
    if(song!=null && song.isPlaying()) song.release();
}
...}
```

**The Adapter code:**

```
public class MyAdapter2 extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter2.MyViewHolder>{
private Context mContext;
private List<CardAudioGrid> mList;
private OnItemClickListener mListener;

public interface OnItemClickListener{
    void onPlayClick (int position);
}
public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener){
    mListener = listener;
}

public MyAdapter2(Context mContext, List<CardAudioGrid> mList) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mList = mList;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.audiocard, viewGroup, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(view, mListener);
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.audioCardBackground.setImageResource(mList.get(position).getCardBackground());
    ...
    holder.mediaPlayer.setImageResource(mList.get(position).getPlayButton());
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mList.size();
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    ImageView mediaPlayer, audioCardBackground;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView, final OnItemClickListener listener) {
        super(itemView);

        mediaPlayer = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.mediaPlayerId);
        audioCardBackground = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardbackgroundId);
        mediaPlayer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(listener!=null){
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                        listener.onPlayClick(position);
                        mediaPlayer.setImageResource(R.drawable.mediapause2);
                    }else{

                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
}
```

How should I solve this problem?

I am currently learning how to manage the android properly, so I would really appreciate if you explain the steps' solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `CardAudioGrid` model initialize a boolean variable `isPlaying = false`

Inside your RecyclerViewAdapter `MyAdapter2` 
declare a integer variable that will hold the position of the currently playing item.

```
int nowPlaying = -1;
```

When an item is clicked, change that item's `isPlaying` value `true/false` according to your need.

Check `nowPlaying`'s value, if its greater than `-1` make that last model's `isPlaying = false`

and assign`nowPlaying` the new clicked position value.

and call `notifyDataSetChanged();`

`onBindViewHolder` don't forget to set your resources according to your dataModel

```
if(mList.get(position).isPlaying())
    holder.mediaPlayer.setImageResource(mList.get(position).getPlayButton());
else
   holder.mediaPlayer.setImageResource(mList.get(position).getStopButton());
```

You can also achieve this without adding a new member to your CardAudioGrid Model class. In that case instead of checking `isPlaying` check

```
if(position == nowPlaying)
   holder.mediaPlayer.setImageResource(mList.get(position).getPlayButton());
else
   holder.mediaPlayer.setImageResource(mList.get(position).getStopButton());
```

Comment: I've tried to implement this you suggested, but the icon isn't changing when I click anymore. I've initialized `isPlaying = false` inside CardAudioGrid constructor. Also, in CardAudioGrid, implemented `public boolean getIsPlaying(){ return isPlaying; }` and `public int getPlayButton() {isPlaying = false; return playButton;}`  and `public int getStopButton() {isPlaying = true;return playButton;}`.
(Continuing in next comment)

Comment: Inside MyAdapter2, implemented the global variable `private int nowPlaying = -1`,
in onBindViewHolder:
`if(position == nowPlaying) holder.mediaPlayer.setImageResource(mList.get(position).getStopButton());
else holder.mediaPlayer.setImageResource(mList.get(position).getPlayButton());`
and in OnClick(View v)
`if(listener!=null){ 
nowPlaying = position; ...` 
and  `if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
...
if(mList.get(position).getIsPlaying())mediaPlayer.setImageResource(R.drawable.mediapause2); 

else mediaPlayer.setImageResource(R.drawable.mediaplay2); `

Comment: I assumed getPlayButton() returns  an Image Resource. and also are you calling notifyDataSetChanged() after clicking an item?

Comment: do not set your image resource inside MyViewHolder Class. change your image resource inside onViewBinder method.

Comment: use getLayoutPosition() instead of getAdapterPosition(); 
check the link https://pastebin.com/WU61GuDC

Comment: Yea, I got it! Thanks!!